# Google Analytics API: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

I have been looking for a solution to this, but since I'm a newbie I might be missing something obvious? I'm playing with the Quick Start example, trying to set a batch request, because I'm trying to learn how they work :).

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Batching test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="<MyID>">
 <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly">
 <!-- Load the JavaScript API client and Sign-in library. -->
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:platform.js""></script>
  <!--<script src="/batching/script.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello Analytics Reporting API V4</h1>

<!-- The Sign-in button. This will run `queryReports()` on success. -->
<p class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="batchExecution"></p>
<script>
    var VIEW_ID = '3213999';

var sessionsM = 'ga:sessions';
var transactionsM = 'ga:transactions';
  // Query the API and print the results to the page.
/*gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
  console.log('hi');
  });*/
  var analyticsReportRequest = function queryReports(chooseMetric) {
    gapi.client.request({
      path: '/v4/reports:batchGet',
      root: 'https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/',
      method: 'POST',
      body: {
        reportRequests: [
          {
            viewId: VIEW_ID,
            dateRanges: [
              {
                startDate: '7daysAgo',
                endDate: 'today'
              }
            ],
            metrics: [
              {
                expression: choseMetric
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }).then(displayResults, console.error.bind(console));
  };

var report1 = analyticsReportRequest(sessionsM);
var report2 = analyticsReportRequest(transactionsM);
function batchExecution() {
  var batch = gapi.client.newBatch();
   batch.add(report1);
   batch.add(report2);
}




  function displayResults(response) {
    var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(response.result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('query-output').value = formattedJson;
  }
</script>
<!-- The API response will be printed here. -->
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="query-output"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting the following errors (file name is index.html): 
First Error:

```
(index):31 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'request' of undefined
    at queryReports ((index):31)
    at (index):56
```

Second error:

```
cb=gapi.loaded_0:73 Uncaught wY {message: "Batch entry is missing a request method", stack: "gapi.client.Error: Batch entry is missing a reques…zhnSLA1FmTcs72V1b-s3Z55A/cb=gapi.loaded_0:77:300)"}
```

Could someone potentially help me, please?

Many thanks,
J.

Comment: The error message tells you, that `gapi.client` is undefined.

Comment: There's one quotation mark too many: `...:platform.js""></script>`

Comment: Thanks Andreas, sorted that but still getting the same error :(